# Trying to make BLOB to PDF in browser

Tags: pdf, php

I have BLOB information from my database and trying to display a PDF file in browser using this:

```php
echo "<object data='data:application/pdf;base64,".base64_encode($row['PDF_File'])."' type='application/pdf' style='height:600px;width:60%'></object>";
```

But with the result I get a problem like this:

[image: failure]

The error message (originally in Russian) in English is:

> Error
>
> The PDF document could not be loaded.
>
> To reboot

If I change `base64_encode` to `base64_decode` it will crack, if I delete this, it won't show up.

New PDFs are added to DB by JavaScript script:

```javascript
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onload = function() {
console.log(reader.result);
  const data = {
    file_pdf: reader.result
  };
  sendForm(data);
};
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: you should probably provide a translation for any non-english language error messages. is the byte stream in your database base64 encoded? describe how new PDFs are added to the DB.

Comment: Giacomo1968, yea it's pdf.
Frank Thomas, yes, it's encoded. Error says "failed to load PDF file". New PDFs are added to DB by JS script:
```var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function() {
        console.log(reader.result);
        const data = { file_pdf: reader.result };
        sendForm(data);
    };```

Comment: so that covers the clientside upload, but not the serverside (the php or whatever of the post request).  either way I'm still not seeing anything that indicates base64 encoding, so its likely that using base64 encode/decode is not the correct transformation of byte stream. have you just tried returning the file stream contents instead of trying to encode it?

Comment: Yea i tried this, but not working either. All PDFs in my DB starts with "data:application/pdf;base64,"

Comment: Giacomo1968, if I leave it like this, then there is just blank space without document

Comment: Giacomo1968, I commented your answer, maybe something useful there about unexpected upload process?

Comment: Giacomo1968, thank you alot, how can I "upvote" you?

Comment: _"All PDFs in my DB starts with `data:application/pdf;base64,`"_ - then why are you putting _another_ `data:application/pdf;base64,` in front of it, in your output?

Comment: Just a note: You could have reduced the issue. If you can serve a local, verified PDF file, but you can't serve one from the DB, storage from the DB may be your issue. If you can, the problem is not how you put things into the DB.